# php: How do you store 3 pieces of data in one place in an array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a database for a forum, where I store name, id, title, post, **reactions**

In **reactions** I store a serialized array containing all the reactions like this:

Reaction1 => uniqid1, Reaction2 => uniqid2 etc etc.

I made a system where you can remove certain reactions (by the unique id of every reaction) if you are an admin . But I also want people to be able to remove their own reactions.

My idea was to store the serialized array as follows:**$reactions**(Name1 -> Reaction1 -> uniqueid1, Name1=>reaction2=>uniqueid2, etc, etc) so I can modify the system that you may also be able to delete (maybe even edit) your own posted reactions.

What would also work, I've added the name inside the reaction like ($reaction = "posted by **name**: $input") If I could somehow identify this "name" part of the reaction and use that, that would also work in my system, only thing is that using this, if you write someone elses name inside a reaction, that someone else can remove the reaction because his name is contained in there.

If this is possible, I would appreaciate some help on how to do it, if it's not possible, tell me that it's not!

Don't worry for security problems, it's for school and nobody really get's acces to the website.

Thanks for helping!.

Edit: I thought of a different way of solving the problem, I could store the unique reaction ID inside a database assigned to the specific name that commented. This way I could fetch all these results and assign the delete button to the reactions of the specific name.

Comment: I don't know alot about php, this seemed like the biggest brain solution to me.

Comment: In your Edit you are on the right track. Store each reactions with a unique id and the reaction's author.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone in the same situation, use this

```
if (strpos($reaction,$namereaction) === 0){
$canedit = TRUE;
}
else {
$canedit = FALSE;   
}
if ($_SESSION['ADMIN'] == TRUE || $canedit == TRUE) {
    put your things here for the delete button
}
```

With this line of code, you can check if the reaction contains the username at the start of the reaction, this way only yourself or admins can delete the reaction.

Make sure your reaction looks like this: ($name says: $reaction) This way it would work